# Equivalents for Backbone.Router.call() and Backbone.history.start() in grapnel.js.

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

What are the equivalents for Backbone.Router.call() and Backbone.history.start() in grapnel.js. I am looking for a routing library which can replace the existing Backbone Router.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well `Backbone.router.call` is what you would use to override the constructor of an extended Router to call the parent constructor - is that what you are trying to do with Grapnel? You don't need to call a start-like method with Grapnel - when you `new` it, it starts. What exactly are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: @DominicTobias - Thanks a lot, I was able to make some progress with grapnel js. Your inputs helped, would like to follow you if you are on quora or if you have a tech blog of your own.